# Galleria not loading on initial page visit

Tags: jquery, galleria

I'm using the Galleria plug-in for a website I'm setting up, and it was working flawlessly until I tested it on someone else's computer.

On a visitors initial visit to the site, the slideshow will not load at all, but after reloading the page it will appear.  I never had a problem with it while I was building the site, but when I cleared my cache and data and visited the site, I ran into the same problem.

So whats going on here? Is there a simple fix?
Is there a way to just force a page reload upon the initial visit?

[here is the site](http://aleighphoto.com)

On the home page, the first visit (no cache/data/cookies from the site previously) consistently loads without the Galleria plug-in slideshow playing. But after one reload, it works beautifully.
Any help is appreciated.

Don't criticize too much, this is the first site I've made, and it was mostly made through sticking other people's code together.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the exact same behavior.  What fixed it for me was loading the css theme in the html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.css">
```